SPI with Bookworm OS - Change SPI Clock Speed
Is it possible to adjust the Clock speed of the SPI device from the terminal/CLI?

Why do you want to change? What are you doing with SPI?

Ask a complete question, please. Some of those who know answers that may help won't waste their time answering such a vague question.
